# How to get folders in Thunderbird and Gmail to "look" the same?

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, imap

I know that in the advanced settings of Thunderbird, I can set the "imap server directory" to [Gmail].  This puts all of the folders I use on the same "level" in thunderbird, ie:

```
   Inbox
   Archives
   Trash
   Spam
```

But when I logon to Gmail itself, it makes the folders I create have a label of "*[Gmail]\myfolder*".

Is there a way to keep all of the folders on the same level and NOT add the prefix to the label when using gmail.  It would make creating rules & filters SO much easier.

Comment: Rules made in Thunderbird client are  not the same as those made in GMail server, and behave differently. Not sure you'll get a benefit from having the folders appear the same.